# How to set a simple counter in a certain chapter

Tags: equations, counters

> How can I set the equation counter to behave differently for a certain Chapter?

I am writing my phd thesis, and I want to have a simple equation counter for the introduction. In general, depending on Chapter/Section, the equation number looks like (1.2.2) (Chapter 1/Section 2/Equation 2).

I would like that only in the introduction equation numbers would look like (1),(2),(3),etc, and from the next chapter, to regain their general form. How can I do that?

Comment: What class are you using? Is the Introduction before or after `\mainmatter` (if you're using this command)?

Comment: I use the class memoir, and I dont recall using the command `\mainmatter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}}
```

In the intro then

```
\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
```

at the end of the intro.

Comment: Cool. This does exactly what I expected. :)

Comment: Could you do something like `\let\theoldequation\theequation\renewcommand...` at the beginning and then `\let\theequation\theoldequation` at the end?

Comment: @WChargin you could, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Use the package [chngcntr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr?lang=en):

In your preamble:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
```

In the Introduction section:

```
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
```

After the Introduction section:

```
\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}
```